# How can I rewrite URL with GET parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

After many researches, I can't resolve  my problem.

I have this website : http://www.verckeninvest.com/

And I need to rewrite this URL : http://www.verckeninvest.com/index.php?func=ann_in 
to http://www.verckeninvest.com/ann_in

And last step would be : http://www.verckeninvest.com/index.php?func=ann_in&id=200
to http://www.verckeninvest.com/ann_in/200

I tryed many things but no one is working, it only removes the "index.php?" but not the "func=".

Here is my last .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?func=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?func=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I hope you can help me. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I just realised something ! It is working, I just needed to change the URL destination in the code to 
http://www.verckeninvest.com/ann_in/200 and it works ! I thought the wrong way !